# Problem using a component Link in RTF field

Tags: publishing, 2013-sp1, dxa, dynamic-linking, rtf

When I try to use a component link in a RTF field (by using hyperlink) of a component, I get **'Value cannot be null.Parameter name: rootElement'** error while publishing the corresponding page.

The publishing fails every-time and below is the error log:

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: rootElement.    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.Fields.ItemFields..ctor(XmlElement
>   rootElement, Schema schema, Nullable`1 synchronizeFlags, LoadFlags
>   loadFlags)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.Fields.ItemFields..ctor(XmlElement
>   rootElement, Schema schema)    at
>   Sdl.Web.Tridion.Templates.ResolveRichText.b__2(Match
>   match) in
>   D:\TBB\DXA-Templating\Sdl.Web.Templating\Common\ItemFieldsExtensions.cs:line
>   111    at
>   System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexReplacement.Replace(MatchEvaluator
>   evaluator, Regex regex, String input, Int32 count, Int32 startat)
>   at System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(String input,
>   MatchEvaluator evaluator)    at
>   System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(String input, String
>   pattern, MatchEvaluator evaluator)    at
>   Sdl.Web.Tridion.Templates.ResolveRichText.ResolveJsonContent(String
>   content) in
>   D:\TBB-DXA-Templating\Sdl.Web.Templating\Common\ItemFieldsExtensions.cs:line 70    at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Templates.ResolveRichText.Transform(Engine
>   engine, Package package) in
>   D:\TBB\DXA-Templating\Sdl.Web.Templating\Common\ItemFieldsExtensions.cs:line
>   66    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Assembly.AssemblyMediator.Transform(Engine
>   engine, Template template, Package package)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Assembly.CSharpSourceCodeMediator.RunTemplate(Engine
>   engine, Package package, String templateUri, String className)    at
>   Tridion.Templating.CSharpTemplate.CSharpSourceTemplate.Transform(Engine
>   __engine, Package __package)    at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Assembly.CSharpSourceCodeMediator.Transform(Engine
>   engine, Template template, Package package)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.ExecuteTemplate(Template
>   template, Package package)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.InvokeTemplate(Package
>   package, TemplateInvocation templateInvocation, Template template)
>   at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Compound.CompoundTemplateMediator.Transform(Engine
>   engine, Template templateToTransform, Package package)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.ExecuteTemplate(Template
>   template, Package package)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.InvokeTemplate(Package
>   package, TemplateInvocation templateInvocation, Template template)
>   at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Compound.CompoundTemplateMediator.Transform(Engine
>   engine, Template templateToTransform, Package package)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.ExecuteTemplate(Template
>   template, Package package)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.InvokeTemplate(Package
>   package, TemplateInvocation templateInvocation, Template template)
>   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.TransformItem(Template
>   template, IdentifiableObject itemToRender)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Debugging.DebuggingEngine.Run()
>   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Debugging.DebugSession.Run()

The component link works fine for multimedia items.
Any idea about this issue?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the DXA templating code ResolveRichText TBB... does the schema of your linked component have metadata? If not can you try adding a metadata field?

Comment: It worked after I added a metadata field....So this is perhaps why multimedia items are working (since they have metadata fields)? What can be a proper solution? (We are using beta version of java dxa. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug in the ResolveRichText TBB. This TBB puts metadata from the linked component into data attributes on link, which can then be read and used for processing when the content is being rendered (an example of this is the YouTube video YouTubeId, which enables the link to be converted into an embedded video). I guess there is a problem if there is no metadata. Looking at the [latest DXA source code for the template](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-content-management/blob/master/Sdl.Web.Templating/Templates/ResolveRichText.cs#L94) this should not be a problem, as it does a check to see if the meta is not null. I guess you are using an older version of the source (perhaps [this one](https://github.com/bkoopman/tri/blob/master/content-management/Sdl.Web.Templating/Templates/ResolveRichText.cs#L72)), in which case you will need to either upgrade DXA to the latest, or manually patch the TBB code yourself.